# ERROR [07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1

Tags: sql, csv, odbc

[image]I am having this problem when trying to query the ODBC CSV file.  It is coming up with this error message. My plan is to format the date and after this I will start to do the count process based on each day on each AC Serial.

```
ERROR [07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.It is strange.


SELECT  DSN, Format([Date Time],  "yyyy-MM-dd")
From  a1.csv 
Group by [DSN],Format([Date Time],  "yyyy-MM-dd");`
```

Comment: The `FORMAT` function expects three parameters (not in order):(1) Input, (2) data type and (3) output format. Google for the correct syntax.

Comment: @FDavidov, I google your suggestion. The third parameters is culture, which does not matter. You are confusing....

Comment: Please add a sample (piece) of the input CSV file.

Comment: I have put a screen shot in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might have similar issue. If possible it is better to use OLEDB than to use ODBC as data source.The OLEDB Connection string as follow :

```
OLE DB Connection String 

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\temp\\csv;Mode=Read;Extended Properties="text;HDR=YES;FMT=CSVDelimited"
```

And also the SQL code working now is  :

```
SELECT        [HC SERIAL CODE], Startdate, COUNT(*) AS Expr2
FROM            (SELECT DISTINCT DSN, [HC SERIAL CODE], Format([Date time], 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS Startdate
                          FROM            a1.csv) a
GROUP BY Startdate, [HC SERIAL CODE]
ORDER BY Startdate
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is that you're using double quotes instead of single quotes around the dates formats. ODBC is less tolerant of SQL variations.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that the format of the input `DATE TIME` is not interpreted as an actual DATETIME value but as a string, and hence the use of the `FORMAT` function cannot work.

I made a brief check of my assumption, and tried this, which works for me (though didn't check the grouping):

```
declare @1 TABLE (DSN INT , timestamp VARCHAR(64) ) ;

insert into @1 VALUES (123 , '10/02/2018 12:20:00'),
                      (123 , '13/02/2018 22:20:00'),
                      (123 , '13/02/2018 22:20:00'),
                      (124 , '13/02/2018 22:20:00'),
                      (124 , '14/02/2018 22:20:00'),
                      (124 , '14/02/2018 22:20:00')  ;

select DSN , (SUBSTRING(timestamp,7,4) + '-' + 
              SUBSTRING(timestamp,4,2) + '-' + 
              SUBSTRING(timestamp,1,2)         ) AS BLABLA
```

from @1 ;

Being the result:

```
DSN BLABLA
123 2018-02-10
123 2018-02-13
123 2018-02-13
124 2018-02-13
124 2018-02-14
124 2018-02-14
```

Comment: I will give you update on the testing. The date time is a column and is formated as char in the csv. When i define the format from char to date in odbc configuration. It return null. My option now is is to use your suggestion. I am far from.my PC now.

Comment: Don't worry. I'm not in a hurry :-).

Comment: I used the code as this but us still coming up with error invalid sql statement expected DELETE, INSERT or UPDATE                                                              
                                                                                                                      :  declare @1  a1.csv  (DSN INT , [Date Time]  VARCHAR(64)  ) 

select DSN , (SUBSTRING([Date Time] ,7,4) + '-' + 
              SUBSTRING([Date Time] ,4,2) + '-' + 
              SUBSTRING([Date Time] ,1,2)         ) AS DATESTART

FROM  @1;

Comment: I have changed the datasource to the OLEDB. I can now format but am getting error counting the download without duplicate for each day ... I will raise another question regarding this.....

Comment: I got it to work using OLEDB. I do not know why ODBC is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because the DBF file had been changed and one of the columns in my SELECT statement was no longer in the DBF file.  Changing the SELECT statement to match the DBF columns fixed the issue.